# apachectl reports that it's in worker mode, however the configuration seems to be set to prefork

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, httpd.conf, mpm-prefork

I'm using a VPS running Apache2.4 and CentOS7. I'm hitting some threading issues and would like to try to run Apache in prefork mode.

If I run `apachectl -V` to check which mode I'm in, I get this result:

```
Server MPM:     worker
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
```

However when I check the MPM conf (`/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf`), I see that the prefork module has been loaded:

```
#HTTPD=/usr/sbin/httpd.worker
#OPTIONS=
HTTPD_LANG=C
#PIDFILE=/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid

# Select the MPM module which should be used by uncommenting exactly
# one of the following LoadModule lines:
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so
#LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
```

And further if I check `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` I see the the worker line is commented out:

```
#HTTPD=/usr/sbin/httpd.worker
#OPTIONS=
HTTPD_LANG=C
#PIDFILE=/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid
```

I've checked that this configuration is actually applied to the instance of Apache that I'm using. For example the pattern `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/*.conf` is Included into my `httpd.conf` file. Is it likely these options are being overwritten somewhere, or am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue; There was another conf file `/etc/apache2/conf.modules.d/000_mod_mpm_worker.conf` which loads `mpm_worker_module`. I tried to uncomment the `LoadModule` line in this file, but then I got an error from Apache on restart telling me that no MPM module is loaded. The final solution was to change this file to `000_mod_mpm_prefork.conf` and load `mpm_prefork_module` inside it.